# How to tell somone at random you want to speak with him using only numbers and the first 4 letters of the Alphabet?

Tags: word, language

There’s a [token on Ethereum](https://etherscan.io/address/0x3dae53ee778a324bd317bd270d6227406b6bd4ed) which seems to be very [famous](https://etherscan.io/token/0x2cc5ef81006d70c6ad3eae4d46842b41d0716071) according to the number of peoples using it and the amount of money collected.

But yet, Googling the function names as well as the `Stellar del Futoro` (the name of the Ethereum token) yells no website at all whereas an ᴀʙɪ file is required to use such kind of smart‑contract and since it’s not on Etherscan, it needs to be on a website (obviously the one from the organization managing the project).

So the best way to get more information would be to ask some users at random. The Ethereum system allows to send data to anyone in hex, which means using numbers and the letters from A to F (even using spaces is impossible).

Now that I explained the purpose, **the part which isn’t related to technology (and can be used in other contexts like in the street) : how do you tell to someone at random you want to ask him/her a question using numbers and the letters from A to F** in a way he/she recognize this isn’t just like that but this is text and that you want a reply ?

## Update

The purpose might be on topic but the question is: What if for a different reason it would had to be done using a paper?

Comment: So far I only found `0x000000000000000000DeaD` which doesn’t seems to yield any reply from the peoples who received it.

Comment: `0xDEADBEEF` is another funny hex text - might prompt a conversation from some systems programmers

Comment: @Avi oh something I forgot: the message has to be exactly 512 characters long (missing characters are automatically added as bunch of 0). The peoples using this are power users who gamble a lot of their money but often no nothing about programming. Last time I found something like this, they where in China.

Comment: This seems like a *problem* you might want to solve, but not a *puzzle* -- there's not really a definite solution, and answers will be highly subjectively valid.

Comment: @Deusovi but the solution of the problem is the solution of a puzzle. Though a puzzle which might not have any existing solutions.

Comment: I have to be honest and say I'm not sure what you're asking or why you're asking it. You should edit this to fully explain the context and the requirements.

Comment: @F1Krazy I want to know the website of the smart contract (which is off chain resources) in order to know it’s purpose. As I didn’t found anything despite the large number of different users using it (meaning it’s popular), this requires asking one of there users what this about using the only limited available.

Comment: How about "FACE2FACE" or "FEEDBAC" or a combination?

Comment: @Jens while this means something, I don’t think the other party will get the idea it requires a reply.

Comment: This question seems pretty clearly off-topic: it doesn't appear to be related to puzzles except incidentally in that one of the possible methods might be vaguely similar to a puzzle. A question that depends this much on human interpretation is going to be one where any answer is subjectively correct.

Comment: @Deusovi this isn’t not a possible method, but the only method.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that the person you are contacting has puzzle-solving skills:

> 1234567890ABCDEFA5C1101492077616E7420746F2074616C6B20746F20796F7503

A breakdown:

> 1234567890ABCDEF

The first 16 digits are just 1 to 16 in HEX, to get their attention and show that this isn't random

> A5C11

i.e. Ascii, to help them decode the next bit

> 01492077616E7420746F2074616C6B20746F20796F7503

The Message, in Hex-encoded Ascii, including "Start of Text" and "End of Text" tags:

```
 01  49  20  77  61  6E  74  20  74  6F  20  74  61  6C  6B  20  74  6F  20  79  6F  75  03
 SOT|"I"|" "|"W" "A" "N" "T"|" "|"T" "O"|" "|"T" "A" "L" "K"|" "|"T" "O"|" "|"Y" "O" "U"|EOT
```

Comment: Judging by the daily activity peak, the thing seems to be Asian which means they don’t have English phonemes in mind. Also all attempts to send the most basic ASCII encoded English message failed (though all software required to use Ethereum like this use only the Latin alphabet).

Answer (score -1):

```
0900230919080020150001191100251521000100172105192009151400161205011905001805161225
```

This tells the person it's not a random string because it has no letters. (The chances of that occurring at random in a message this length if characters are chosen uniformly is minuscule.) And then the fact there are a bunch of `00`s in it will hopefully lead him to look at pairs of numbers, which will show him that none go beyond 25 and thus get him to translate them into letters of the alphabet (with `00` for space).

Comment: Could you explain how this meets the OP's requirements?

Comment: @F1Krazy done, methinks

Comment: @msh210 if you received a sms like this from a casino, I hugely doubt you would get the idea that this prompt a reply (despite what you’re stating is true).